# Как указать текстовое значение в теге a

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не совсем тривиальная задача, как мне кажется. Есть тег a. И по клику на него происходит переход на другую страницу. Подскажите, как я могу передать любое текстовое значение тегом a. Спасибо.

Comment: Страницы на одном и том же домене? Какое количество текста предполагается передавать?

Comment: Да, один и тот же домен. Передавать нужно буквально одно слово.

Comment: т.е. необходимое значение должно указываться внутри структуры тега a

Comment: `<a href="/some-page?text=some-value">link</a>` что-то вроде такого вам нужно?

Comment: Думаю, что да. Но необходимо, что бы урл оставался прежним. Вот моя структура тега a - <a class="search_me_tag" href="/blog?text=some-value" title="123">блоге</a>

Comment: И не подскажете, как мне "?text=some-value" передать в alert?

Comment: Никак (но это не точно). Это вам нужно в джаваскрипте вешать обработку на событие `onclick` нужной ссылки, в обработчике события читать из ссылки нужное слово (тогда наверное логичнее будет делать ссылку `<a href="#some-value">link</a>` и алертить его)