# как передать значение параметра title или name тега a, get'ом

Tags: javascript, html, get

Есть тег a. По клику происходит переход на другую страницу. И у данного тега есть параметр title="test_text". Как я могу передать значение "test_text", параметра title, на страницу перехода? На пример, с помощью GET. Срочно нужно. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Вам уже ответили в предыдущем вопросе. Передайте в параметры запроса: `href=http://url?title=test_text`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как указать текстовое значение в теге a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1134487/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b5-a)